# Trying to access classes from package

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm developing an android test app and i'm going to access all internal class of  android.view package. android.view is a package that is present in jar file. I tried by loading package name but it doesn't display the classes here i use the filters and classLoadersList still i did't get output in listview if any one tried this already, please help

```
public class ClassDisplay_list {
    public int i,j;

    public static void main(){
        Log.i("in display main function" ,"i am ");

        List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();

        classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.getContextClassLoader());
        classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.getStaticClassLoader());

        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(), new ResourcesScanner())
            .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
            .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix("android.view"))));

        Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
        Iterator it=classes.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            Class c=(Class)it.next();
            String classname = c.getName();
            ClassesDisplayActivity.your_array_list3.add(classname);
            Log.i("Ram","class name "+ c.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for asking but what do you want to achieve? You can just download the Android source code and look into it?

Comment: The "Android Open Source Project" (AOSP): https://source.android.com/source/index.html it contains the source code of the Android platform.